# Integrating $ x \phi(x, \mu, \sigma) $

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I am trying to compute the following integral:
$$\int x \cdot \phi (x) dx $$
... where $\phi(x)$ is the normal density function with mean $\mu$ and stdev $\sigma$.
Owen (1980), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions, states the solution as:

$$\int x \phi(a+bx) dx = - \frac{1}{b^2}(\phi(a+bx)+a \Phi(a+bx)) + C $$

In order to test out the solution, I have tried to compute the integral for a couple of example values using the built in integrate function in `R`. One example is:

```
mu <- 10
sigma <- 5
x <- 15

tst <- function(x, mu, sigma){
  return(x * dnorm(x, mu, sigma))
}

integrate(tst, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, lower = -Inf, upper = x, abs.tol = 0)$value
> 7.203594
```

... where the result of roughly 7.2 makes intuitively good sense. However, when I use Owen's function, I get a completely different result. Again, in `R` (where I have assumed that $a = \mu$ and $b = \sigma$):

```
-(1/sigma^2) * (dnorm(mu+sigma*x)+mu*pnorm(mu+sigma*x))
> -0.4
```

I am probably missing something or using Owen's integral improperly since I would expect to get the same results using the integrate function in `R` and Owen's formula. Can you help me identify why the two are not equal?

Comment: Just use a substitution $t=x^2$ to get the integral in terms of the Gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$$
$$I=\int x  \,\phi(a+bx)\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int x e^{-\frac{(a +bx-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dx$$ Let $a+bx=t$ to make
$$I=\frac{1}{b^2\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int (t-a)\,e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dt$$
$$\int (t-a)\,e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dt=\int t\,e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dt-a\int e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dt$$
$$\int t\,e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \mu  \sigma \, \text{erf}\left(\frac{t-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)-\sigma ^2 e^{-\frac{(t-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$$ Back to $x$
$$I=\frac{\sigma  (\mu -a) }{2
   b^2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{a+b x-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)-\frac{\sigma ^2 }{\sqrt{2 \pi } b^2}e^{-\frac{(a+b x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can first transform the integral to evaluate the expression easier,
\begin{equation}
I=\int \phi(a+bx)xdx=\int \phi(y)\frac{y-a}{b}dx\\
\end{equation}
Using the fact that $x\phi(x)=-\phi'(x)dx$
\begin{eqnarray}
I=\frac{1}{b}\int \phi(y)\frac{y-a}{b}dy=\frac{1}{b^2}\int \phi(y)ydx-\frac{a}{b^2}\int \phi(y)ydx\\=\frac{-\phi(y)}{b^2}-\frac{a}{b^2}\Phi(y)=\frac{-\phi(a+bx)}{b^2}-\frac{a}{b^2}\Phi(a+bx)+C
\end{eqnarray}
which is Owen's result.
When do a numerical test sticking to the original integral parametrization we see that they coincide in first having full $\infty$ boundaries and a truncated boundary, $x=-2$. Actually when we evaluate Owen's integral at $\infty$ and $a=10,b=5$ we see the result $\frac{-a}{b^2}$ which is indeed -0.4.

```
fx<-function(x,a,b){x*dnorm(a+b*x)}
 b=5
 a=10
 integrate(fx,-Inf,Inf,a=a,b=b)
-0.4 with absolute error < 7.8e-07
 integrate(fx,-15,15,a=a,b=b)
-0.4 with absolute error < 3.3e-05
fI<-function(x,a,b){-1/b^2*(dnorm(a+b*x)+a*pnorm(a+b*x))}
fI(Inf,a,b)
[1] -0.4
integrate(fx,-Inf,-2,a=a,b=b)
-0.2159577 with absolute error < 5.8e-05
fI(-2,a,b)
[1] -0.2159577
```